# can't edit circle in edit mode

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, edit-mode

I am trying create a circle in blender 2.79.
But in edit mode, I can't see some point (read line in end 2nd picture). Can you tell me how to setting it same with 2nd pictue?

[image: my blender]

[image: on youtube]

Comment: finally, I was find solution.

Comment: please post solution for others to find.

Comment: You can check solution in this image (increase Normal Size)

https://screenshots.firefox.com/7lDRj6OBk284Us3X/i.imgur.com

Comment: Shame you didn't bother to take time to actually show your solution